# How to print a board with coordinates?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with some coordinates and True or False for each coordinate.
lets say this one:

```
{(0, 0): False, (0, 1): False, (1, 0): True, (1, 1): False}
```

i want to make a def which takes this dictionary and prints the board with an empty  square if its false on the coordinate or filled square if its true on the coordinate. 
So far I have write this:

```
def printboard(board):
    sizer = int(get_size(board))
    for x in range(sizer):
        falseCount = 0
        trueCount = 0
        for y in range(sizer):
            if board[x,y] == False:
                falseCount += 1
            if board[x,y] == True:
                trueCount += 1
        print('⬛'*trueCount + '⬜'*falseCount)
```

but when I compile it it doesnt prints the true squares.
Does anyone know how to make this work?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is `get_size`?

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: How does this print the board?  For each row, this prints all of the filled squares first, then all of the empty ones, without regard to their actual placement.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you research on line how other gamesters represent simple playing areas.  The typical method is with a NumPy array or a nested list, rather than this dict format.  The 2D layout is easier to index and manipulate for virtually all purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to count at all,you can use `print`'s with `end=""`:

```
def printboard(board):
    mx = max(x for x,_ in board.keys() )
    my = max(y for _,y in board.keys() )

    for y in range(my+1):
        for x in range(mx+1): 
            print('⬛' if board[(x,y)] else '⬜', end= "") 
        print("") 

#           x  y
print('⬛' if board[(x,y)] else '⬜', end= "") False})
```

Output:

```
⬜⬛
⬜⬜
```

This will put in the correct line breaks and work with non-rectangular inputs.

Comment: Why did u used falsecount and truecount in your code?

Comment: the last line what is about? #           x  y
print('⬛' if board[(x,y)] else '⬜', end= "") False})

Comment: it is called a ternary it `print( ........ )` s something - what is printed depends on the ternary:  **dark block** `if board[(x,y)]` is True `else` _white block_

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
x = {
    (0, 0): False, (0, 1): False, 
    (1, 0): True,  (1, 1): False
}

# build a board and fills it with True (⬜)
def build_board(size):
    board = []
    for i in range(size):
        board += [[]]
        for j in range(size):
            board[i] += ['⬜']
    return board 

# fills False entries in the board from the dict (⬛)
def fill_board(data, board):
    for key, value in x.items():
        if value == False:
            board[key[0]][key[1]] = '⬛'
    return board   

# prints the board
def print_board(board):
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            print(board[i][j], end = "")
        print()

## testing the functions
if __name__ == '__main__':
    board = build_board(2)
    board = fill_board(x, board)
    print_board(board)
```

output :

```
⬛⬛
⬜⬛
```